# Why is s not being overridden as a global variable?

Tags: javascript

randomsub is generated via a random number generate not shown, and is a global variable. No song name for this song. (May be an error) is being shown and not overridden by the s = in the function

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = "No song name for this song. (May be an error)";
    var l = randomsub;
        function Name(){
           
                if (l == 0){
                   
                    s = "Tobu - Seven";
                }
                if (l == 1){
                   
                    s = "Tobu - Colors";
                }
                if (l == 2){
                   
                    s = "Tobu - Candyland";
                }
                if (l == 3){
                   
                    s = "Tobu - Such Fun";
                }
                if (l == 4){
                   
                    s = "Tobu - Dreams";
                }
        }
   
   
</script>
<font color="red"><p id="song"><p></font>
<script>
song = document.getElementById("song");
song.innerHTML = s;
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you actually calling the `Name()` function?

Comment: There is no "else" statement on your code, so there is no 100% sure that "s" will be overridden. And are you sure that "randomsub" is set before calling "Name()"?

Answer (score 3):

You are never calling your function `Name`.

add `Name();` before last line and `s` will be overwritten

```
<script>
  song = document.getElementById("song");
  Name();
  song.innerHTML = s;
</script>
```

Also just consider using objects as hashmaps when you need to do a lot of if statements/switch-case statements like you have. You code can be rewritten as:

```
function Name() {
   var names = {
     0: "Tobu - Seven",
     1: "Toby - Colors",
     2: "Tobu - Candyland",
     3: "Tobu - Such Fun",
     4: "Tobu - Dreams"
   }

   if (l in names) {
      s = names[l]
   }
}
```

This way it is much easier to add new options, like `5: "Tobu - Horrors"`